# slickgrid how do you make the header row not scroll up and away

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I just started using slickgrid. I was trying to find out how to make the header row not scroll away as the user scrolls down in the browser so long as part of the table is visible. I could not find any grid option or api method that does that.

Is this possible to do using a slickgrid api? My apologies if this has been asked before - I could not find it in search.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what method you used for that.
I suggest you that us **scrollRowIntoView**

```
mySlickGrid.scrollRowIntoView(90, 6);
```

`scrollCellIntoView` takes in a row as an argument that needed for colspan support. Without it, SlickGrid wouldn't be able to uniquely identify the cell